# wcf 4 netTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I was seting up a wcf 4 service today with netTcpBinding, and I just couldn't get it to work.

It was of course no problem getting basdicHttpBinding to work since little config is needed in WCF 4.

I started wondering if it is even possible to get netTcpBinding working when debbuging through VS10.  I'm hosting my service in a svc-file since I'm planning on hosting it in the IIS (7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.42spikes.com/post/Using-Silverlight-4-and-NetTCP-Duplex-Callbacks.aspx) is a link that I found usefull when I was previously looking into NetTcpBinding.

Comment: This link helped out great, I was suspecting that the VS10-webserver wasn't able to use net.tcp so the service has to be hosted in the IIS.